# How to access the PC Keyboard Buffer for Detecting multiple key press and key release?

Tags: c

I am making a harmonium synthesizer software for PC in C language, for that I have to detect multiple keypress and keyrelease so that to play notes simultaneously accordingly. So, I am thinking that accessing the keyboard buffer would be helpful. But I don't know how to. So can anyone suggest the method to do so or some new idea to detect multiple keypress. For detecting single keypress and keyrelease I have made following C code using kbhit() and getch() functions:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>

void keypress(char);
void delay(int);

int flag=0;

int main()
{
    char c;

    while(1)
    {
        if(kbhit())
        {
            c=getch();

            printf("\nCharacter:%c",c);

            getch();

            keypress(c);

            printf("\nKey Released");

        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void keypress(char ch)
{
    char c;

    delay(50);

    if(kbhit())
    {
        c=getch();

        if(c==ch)
        {
            keypress(c);
        }

    }
}

void delay(int milliSeconds)
{
    clock_t final_time = milliSeconds + clock();
    while (final_time > clock());
}
```

But it has some issues like:-

1).Multiple keypress not detected

2).It generates a very small delay

So can anybody suggest Improvement to code to solve the above issue or some new techniques for detecting multiple key press and key release.

Platform:-Windows 8.1

It would be good if the solution would platform friendly.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the PC keyboard like a piano keyboard, to hold several keys at the same time? You might like to consider the WINAPI function [GetKeyboardState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This is DOS programming, not Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to use the Windows `GetAsyncKeyState` function. It does not need to be in a GUI - this console app works as shown. It will be up to you to examine the bit status flags [as documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine action. For example, auto-repeat is honoured when a key is pressed. You probably won't need to check every key either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned short buff[256] = {0};
    unsigned short kval;
    int i;
    while (1) {
        for(i=0; i<256; i++) {
            kval = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
            if(kval != buff[i]) {
                printf("%02X:%04X ", i, kval);
                buff[i] = kval;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this test, the first line was output before I pressed any key. The second line was output when I pressed and released `'A'`.

```
0D:0001 26:0001 45:0001 53:0001 54:0001 0D:0000 26:0000 45:0000 53:0000 54:0000
41:8001 41:8000 41:0000
```

Note: linked with `user32.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

As you include conio.h, the solution is already tied to a Windows (or MS/DOS) platform.

Here as i assume you do not really need a command line program, the best way would be build a Windows GUI program having an event loop and directly processing the `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages to be alerted as soon as a key is pressed on released on the keyboard. To avoid any risk of loosing one change in the state of the key, you could even consistently use the `GetKeyboardState` API function to load the current state of all keys on the keyboard.

I know this is more a hint that a precise answer, but a detailed answer would be much too long for a SO post.